# Powershell recursively return paths but limit depth to 3

Tags: powershell, directory, copy

In PowerShell, how might one return a set of paths but limit the depth of the result to 3

Here is my folder structure...

```
d:\testfiles\run\test01\success\build
d:\testfiles\run\test01\success\result
d:\testfiles\run\test02\fail\build
d:\testfiles\run\test02\fail\result
d:\testfiles\run\test03\exp\ready\build
d:\testfiles\run\test03\exp\ready\result
```

This command returns the full list of folders

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory d:\testfiles\run\ -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "build|result"} | % { $_.FullName }
```

What I would like to get is the list of folders truncated to 3 deep, ie...

```
d:\testfiles\run\test01
d:\testfiles\run\test01
d:\testfiles\run\test02
d:\testfiles\run\test02
d:\testfiles\run\test03
d:\testfiles\run\test03
```

So, this seems to return the folders as expected...

```
Get-ChildItem -directory -recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^test01$|^test02$|^test03$"} | % { $_.fullname.split('\')[0..3] + '' -join '"\"' -replace ':"\\', ':\' -replace '\\"$', ''}
```

But this throws an error...

```
Get-ChildItem -directory -recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^test01$|^test02$|^test03$"} | Move-Item -Destination { $_.fullname.split('\')[0..3] + '' -join '"\"' -replace ':"\\', ':\' -replace '\\"$', ''}
```

The error I get...

```
Move-Item : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:109
```

Comment: Since PowerShell 5.0 `Get-ChildItem` has a parameter [`-Depth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem#-depth).

Comment: Do you want to limit the _search_ to that depth, or you want to still do a full recursive search and then truncate the (resulting) paths to 3rd sub-folder?

Comment: I want to do a full recursive search and then truncate the resulting paths

Comment: Change `$_.FullName` to `$_.FullName -replace '^([^\\]*(\\[^\\]*){3}).*$','$1'`

Comment: `($_.FullName -split '\\')[0..3] -join '\'` instead of `$_.FullName` inside `ForEach-Object` body?